# Update UI only if data received via AJAX is different

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ashx

I have an HTML list which is being filled with data that's collected via an ASHX AJAX call. This AJAX call is triggered every 1/2 second.

I only want the `#menu` to update if the data received from the AJAX call is different from the existing data within the list. How would I be able to achieve this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  loadMenuHandler();

  function loadMenuHandler() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'MenuHandlerAsync.ashx',
      method: 'get',
      dataType: 'json',
      async: true,
      success: function(data) {
        if (!isCreated) {
          buildMenu($('#menu'), data); //$('#menu') is a ul list
          isCreated = true;
        }

        setTimeout(function() {
          $("#menu").empty();
          buildMenu($('#menu'), data);
          loadMenuHandler();
          showCorrectMenu();
          showCorrectMenuMobile();
          ProcessNotifications();
        }, 1000);
      },
      error: function(err) {
        console.log(err.statusText);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: I would strongly suggest you change the pattern you're using here. AJAX polling, especially at the low interval you're using, will massively impair server performance with very minimal load. If you need to keep the client side UI and server side data in very close sync use Websockets. As a corollary this will also solve your issue of only showing new data, as you can configure the socket to only emit data when new information is available on the server. The server performance using this model (also known as the Observer pattern) will be an order of magnitude better than what you have now.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan any chance I can get help implementing this as a start? thank you

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan my orginal thought was to store data into an array and then compare the two arrays to check if they are equal

Comment: That would work short term, but as I mentioned above you will hit performance issues with polling. There's nothing I can really guide you with in terms of implementing this as you need to re-engineer how the server interacts with the UI. If you research websockets there is a lot of information to get you started